# Is it possible to create Fischer projections (or similar) from SMILES expressions?

Tags: molecular-structure

I've recently begun experimenting with drawing molecules from smiles expressions for use in an educational website. I am looking for a way to create simple structural representations of various molecules in metabolic pathways (Kreb's cycle, Gluconeogenesis, etc) in what I believe is Fisher projections (or similar?), as is often encountered in text books, for example the molecule Citrate:

[image: Citrate Lewis]

Since I'm creating my website in Python I tried using rdkit but so far have only been able to create drawings with 110° angles.[image: Citrate 110]

The smiles formula I used here is courtesy of pubchem:

> C(C(=O)[O-])C(CC(=O)[O-])(C(=O)[O-])O

Is there any open source tool (preferably in Python) that I could use to create images of the Fischer projections? Or is there a "trick" of how to do this with rdkit? I would be grateful for any help and please excuse if I have botched any of the terminology in question. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross-posted on Matter Modelling and has already been answered there: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10002/724.